# Queue Clean After Power Automate Queue triggers finished

Tags: power-automate, azure-queues

I have a Power automate Flow which triggers when there is a message in azure queue and process the message. Power automate triggers perfectly when there is a item in queue. But after successful process , Message is returning back to the queue. And again getting trigger by power automate. Is there any settings I have to change ?
Can someone help ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I faced the same issue. To resolve this, one way you can do is to add another action called `Delete message (V2)` specifying the required properties in the end. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

[image]